# Which void is called when activity gets resumed from intent

Tags: android, android-intent, void

In my current app, HomeActivity (singleTask) fires up BootActivity. BootActivity fires up HomeActivity again via startActivity. Which void is called when HomeActivity is brought to the front again (it hasn't been stopped and moved on running in the background), it isn't onResume?

Thanks

Comment: I think that the first is onRestart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [onNewIntent ()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29) method is called with a new Intent when the Activity is already created:

> This is called for activities that set launchMode to "singleTop" in their package, [...].
>
> An activity will always be paused before receiving a new intent, so you can count on onResume() being called after this method.

But `onResume()` gets called any time the Activity was paused. And since BootActivity was active, HomeActivity was paused, even though it might not have stopped.